# C# Ressources Files setup

Tags: c#, installation

I have a c# project, and need to access to some word files during run time.
My application is a desktop application so I have 2 projects, the main project and the setup project. 
The current situation: 
I access these files through ;

```
object fileName = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\mydoc.docx";
```

So, in the main project, i added the specifics files into /Debug/bin and into a Ressources Folder (in case the debug folder will be deleted). 
And in the setup project I add the files from the precedent Ressource folder.

For each changement or file added, I have to add/replace it in 2 different folders...

What is the right way to do it ?

Answer (score -1):

I dont know if i understood the problem well enough, but every data that application uses, should be stored in %APPDATA% folder. You will skip the problem with 'permission' to a file.

I was used to use Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly() function to store/read data... But i realized its not good, due to fact that many users can use your application at once, and not every user have permission to save files in there.

If you decided to add them to resources folder, use following code:

ProjectName.Properties.Resources.YourFile